# Using redis to capture peak value of counters

Tags: concurrency, redis, metrics

I have a distributed system that processes sessions (the definition of session is not important for this problem except to note that its a process that has a duration that is larger than a second, usually much larger), where I want to identify what is the largest number of sessions processed concurrently during a given time period.

The basic setup is a Redis database where I increment a counter for every session start and decrement it for every session end. The counter value thereby represents the current concurrency at any given point in time.

My problem is how to generate accurate metric of the peak (max) concurrency at given time slices (say, what was the max concurrency in a given day).

I would like to hear how other people would solve this problem, but my current approach is as follows:

#### Session start

- `INCR counter-name` to increase the current value of the counter
- The result of the increment command is the current value of the counter
- `ZADD collector-name NX <counterval> <uniqueid>` to store the currently known concurrency value in an ordered set. Flake-id can be used for fast id generations, but if the session already has a unique ID - which often is the case - we can just use that.

#### Session end

- `DECR counter-name` to reduce the current concurrency value

#### Each report time period

- `RENAME collector-name tempkey` to take a snapshot of the status and allow workers to start a new collector.
- `ZREVRANGEBYSCORE tempkey +inf -inf WITHSCORES LIMIT 0 1` is run, returning the peak value of the counter since the last check (and the unique id of the session that caused the peak, if it is of any relevance).
- `DEL tempkey` as we don't need it anymore.

Notes:

- The final max calculation is done offline from the counter, and its also only O(log(n)).
- The data entry is also O(log(n)), which might be a problem under high load, but `n` here is the number of entries in the current period so we can just increase our reporting frequency to improve performance (nice side effect - lets increase performance by generating more data!)

Are there any flaws in this setup that I've missed?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not detecting any major flaws in the flow, but the choice of data structure could be improved.

Sorted Sets are comparatively expensive in terms of space and time, and your scenario doesn't utilize their special ability (i.e. ordering). More optimal structures would be a Hash of counters, or the highly-compressed [`BITFIELD`](https://redis.io/commands/bitfield).

Comment: I'm using `ZSET` to get the highest value, otherwise I'd need to iterate over the valves, which will be much worse than O(log(n)).

Comment: Gotach - I missed that LIMIT clause on my mobile and assumed offline meant finding the max, summing or sumthin'. Cool!